# Which is the correct format to return a WebService in Java for Android

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I'm doing a Java web application, for an Android application that I'm doing and I want to consume a WebSerivce.

In my app, I have this class

```
public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {
   private double Latitud;
   private double Longitud;
   private String Edificio;
   private Vector<Punto> Vecinos;
   private int Piso;
   private String Nombre;
   private Integer Imagen;
}
```

So what I want to do is get the values of their attributes via RESTful WebService.
Because I have many Points, I want to create a JSON Array in the server side and process in my application.

My question is, which is the format that I have to consider to create the Array?
Should I make a String, whit the format of a JSON Array o should I have to create a JSON Array?
In the first case, which is the format that I have to give to the String to have a correct structure of a JSON Array?

Because the GET statement of my REST Web Service return a String.

Can you give me an idea of how I have to do this?

Comment: Use gson or some other java library to create the string for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I correct understood you, but you don't have to care about it, there are a lot of libraries to convert java object to/from JSON. I believe the best way is you use a regular Java class and pick up some library to convert the data.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are asking about the format of data that you want to pass on to client side from your server side program.
You can create a JSON Array format from the web service call and enclose it in double quotes -> making it a string.
On the client side, you can use methods like JSON.parse (not sure if it is available in android browsers) to parse the string back into JSON Array.